# How to print back data to excel using spreadsheet gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet, xls, xlsx

I am extracting data from excel using spreadsheet gem in ruby and it is working good. This is the code which does it

```
require 'spreadsheet' 
require 'open-uri' 
url = "Linio_batch1_semantic_24092014.xls" 
book = nil 
a1 = Array.new
a2 = Array.new
open url do |f|
 book = Spreadsheet.open f 
end
book.worksheets.each do |sheet| 
#puts "Sheet called #{sheet.name} has #{sheet.row_count} rows and #{sheet.column_count} columns"
s = sheet.column(5)
s.each do |m|
a1 << m
end
s = sheet.column(6)
s.each do |n|
a2 << n
end
 end
```

I am storing the results in an array. I don't know how to write the results to another new spreadsheet. I need help to write the array results to a new spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like following

```
require 'spreadsheet'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'test'
sheet1.row(0).push "just text","another text"
book.write 'test.xls'
```

You can also refer to [this page](http://makandracards.com/makandra/5361-how-to-create-excel-sheets-with-spreadsheet-gem-and-use-number-formats-for-cells-like-money-or-date) or [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591990/spreadsheet-rails-3-question)